# Creating Excel file in OneDrive

Tags: excel, rest, http, onedrive

I'm trying to integrate with Microsoft OneDrive service. I read API docs and went throw Authorization. Unfortunatelly, there's no info in docs about creating different File types. 
I created a .txt file using HTTP Requests as it's written here https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm .
When I'm trying to create an Excel file this way, it does, but the document doesn't open. I think I need to send some special params (metadata?) also, but I don't know which ones.

I would be very pleased for any help :)

Comment: Hey did you get this done? I am facing same problem. Getting error : We're sorry, we couldn't open your workbook. It's possibly corrupt or using a file format that's not supported.

Do you want to try and open this file in Excel?